# Nested form attributes for has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've scoured SO and the internets for quite a while, but haven't been able to figure this out. I have a model Project, which always has one TimerSetting. No join tables involved.

In the new project form, I'm trying to use nested attributes to create a TimerSetting record. Can't figure this part out.

Relevant code in the models:

Project Model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :timer_setting_id

    has_one :timer_setting
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :timer_setting
end
```

TimerSetting model:

```
class TimerSetting < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :rounding_method, :round_to

    belongs_to :project
end
```

In the project controller:

```
def new
    @project.new
    @project.build_timer_setting
end
```

In the view:

```
<%= form_for @project, {remote: true, format: 'json'} do |f| %>
    ... other stuff ...
    <%= f.fields_for :timer_setting do |ts| %>
      Rounding Method <%= ts.check_box :rounding_method %>
      Round To <%= ts.text_field :round_to %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I call the route to render the form (projects/new), rails is saying: `unknown attribute: project_id`. If I comment out the line in the project controller

```
#@project.build_timer_setting
```

it will render the form, but the fields in the `f.fields_for :timer_setting` block aren't output.

Any advice/help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your TimerSetting needs a project_id. Your Project dosn't neeed the timer_settings_id, because rails will find it through the project_id of your TimerSetting model.